# How to feed images into a CNN for binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a convolutional neural network that can detect whether or not a person is having a stroke, based upon a picture of their face. The images for my dataset are contained within a directory called *CNNImages*, which contains two subdirectories: *Strokes* and *RegularFaces*. Each subdirectory contains jpg images that I'm trying to feed into my neural network.

Following the approach used in [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-convolution-neural-network-in-5-mins-4217c2cf964f), I have created the CNN, which works when fed with the MNIST dataset. However, I am having trouble feeding my own images into the neural network. I have been using the code shown by the [Keras tutorial](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) for Image data preprocessing, but it isn't working.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
 
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'C:\\Users\\Colin\\CNNImages',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(128, 128),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=1,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

When I try to feed this dataset into my neural network using `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = dataset`, I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I've included my attempt at a neural network below.

```
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 2
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 128, 128

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = dataset

x_train = x_train.reshape(869,128,128,3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(217,128,128,3)

print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

I believe I am importing the images incorrectly into the CNN, but am unsure of how to fix this. What would be the solution to getting the images to import correctly?

Edit: Below is my updated code attempt. It is unable to function, due to `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_ds` returning `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
 
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  'C:\\Users\\Colin\\Desktop\\CNNImages\\Training',
  validation_split=None,
  subset=None,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(128, 128),
  batch_size=32)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  'C:\\Users\\Colin\\Desktop\\CNNImages\\Validation',
  validation_split=None,
  subset=None,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(128, 128),
  batch_size=32)


batch_size = 128
num_classes = 2
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 128, 128

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_ds

x_train = x_train.reshape(869,128,128,3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(217,128,128,3)

print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=3
)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = dataset` part of the code raises error. Because, when you use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_director()`, it returns batches of images, **it does not split** your data into train set and test set. So you need to declare seperately for train and test:

```
# first-approach
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(train_folder, ...)
test_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(test_folder, ...)

# second approach
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=3
)
```

Comment: So to fix that, would I just separate out the training and test images into two subdirectories, create the two datasets while setting validation_split and subset equal  to None, and call the training dataset into the CNN with `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_dataset`?

Comment: One way is `yes` or look at the answer, I updated it.

Comment: I implemented the two datasets in the second approach and changed model.fit to reflect the one in your second approach. What should I feed into `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)` in order to get the CNN to work correctly? Or should I replace that line with something else?

Comment: You should remove that line

Comment: x_train, y_train, x_test, and y_test are all used extensively through the CNN. When I delete all mentions of them, the code is unable to function.

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://pastebin.com/Vntew9jR) - final code. If yuor image is rgb then change input shape to (128, 128, 3), if grayscale left it as it was